# Como mudar o tipo de uma coluna no Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Quero alterar o tipo de uma coluna de um arquivo CSV. Usei esse comando:

```
cand_doacoes['CPF_CNPJ_doador'] = cand_doacoes.CPF_CNPJ_doador.astype(int64)
```

Mas aparece o erro:

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-842f431fca9e> in <module>()
----> 1 cand_doacoes['CPF_CNPJ_doador'] = cand_doacoes.CPF_CNPJ_doador.astype(int64)

NameError: name 'int64' is not defined
```

Alguém sabe o comando correto?

Answer (score 2):

Fiz uns testes e se for informado 'int64' entre aspas(string) e conversão ocorre sem problemas.

```
cand_doacoes.CPF_CNPJ_doador.astype('int64')
```

Comment: Obrigado. Funcionou mesmo
Mas deu esse erro depois: ValueError: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer

Creio que é o porque nesta coluna há linhas em branco. Não posso apagar essas linhas. A solução é converter as linhas em branco para "0"? Ou há algum outro comando?

Comment: Vou fazer alguns testes aqui e depois dou feedback.

Comment: Os valores da coluna CPF_CNPJ_doador são somente números, sem os pontos?

Comment: Se a coluna contém somente numeros, vc poderia fazer um laço antes da conversão, preenchendo com '0' as celulas vazias, assim: cand_doacoes['CPF_CNPJ_doador'] = [x if x.isdigit() else '0' for x in cand_doacoes.CPF_CNPJ_doador]

Answer (score 0):

Você pode preencher os dados ausentes com `0` zeros usando o método `fillna`

```
cand_doacoes['CPF_CNPJ_doador'].fillna(0)
```

Essa forma é mais fácil. Depois você muda o nome e/ou o tipo da coluna.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar varios tipos, eu costumo utilizar o:

**Para Inteiro**

```
df.NOME_DA_COLUNA = pd.to_numeric(df.NOME_DA_COLUNA , errors='coerce')
```

**Para formatar Data em String**

```
import datetime
from datetime import date
df["DT_NASC"] = pd.to_datetime(df["DT_NASC"], errors='coerce').dt.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
```

**Para formatar A Coluna para String**

```
df['NOME_DA_COLUNA '] = df['NOME_DA_COLUNA '].astype(str)
```

Answer (score -3):

for coluna, config in tipos_colunas.items():
df[coluna] = df[coluna].astype(config)